# HighCharts exporting filename

Tags: javascript, highcharts, export

I am using highcharts exporting module to export charts as pdf. In my code I have created a snippet `chart` object that gets manipulated on different gui controls being used. It looks something like this:

```
options = {
   ...
   ...
   exporting:{
      type: "application/pdf",
      filename: "default",

      buttons:{
        exportButton:{
            menuItems: null,
            onclick:function(){
                var fileName = "AAAA";//it's dynamic in reality.
                alert(options.exporting.filename);//alerts "default"
                options.exporting.filename = fileName;
                alert(options.exporting.filename);//alerts "AAAA"
                this.exportChart();
             }
         },
         printButton: {
             enabled: false
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Now whenever the export button is clicked the downloaded file is named as `default.pdf` while the alerts show that the property has been changed.

Also since the first alert shows the result as `default`(which is not the default value, its `chart` actually) its clear that I am referencing the correct property, so no chance that of error due to setting filename in a wrong property.

Can anyone explain the situation or suggest changes to make me download the file with dynamic names.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the filename of the file.  Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/PMyHQ/392/) on how to accomplish that.  The relevant code:

```
exportButton: {
    menuItems: null,
    onclick: function() {
        chart.exportChart({filename: 'my-png'}, null);
    }
},
```

Here is another [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/348sh/3/) that shows a little more on what can be controlled during export and printing.  The relevant code:

```
$('#buttonExport').click(function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("ExportOption");
    var ExportAs = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;   

    if(ExportAs == 'PNG')
    {
        chart.exportChart({type: 'image/png', filename: 'my-png'}, {subtitle: {text:''}});
    }
    if(ExportAs == 'JPEG')
    {
        chart.exportChart({type: 'image/jpeg', filename: 'my-jpg'}, {subtitle: {text:''}});
    }
    if(ExportAs == 'PDF')
    {
        chart.exportChart({type: 'application/pdf', filename: 'my-pdf'}, {subtitle: {text:''}});
    }
    if(ExportAs == 'SVG')
    {
        chart.exportChart({type: 'image/svg+xml', filename: 'my-svg'}, {subtitle: {text:''}});
    }
}); 

$('#buttonPrint').click(function() {
    chart.setTitle(null, { text: ' ' });
    chart.print();
    chart.setTitle(null, { text: 'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' });
});
```

Comment: I want to show title when print chart but I did it like this.
chart.setTitle({text:'SOme title'});
chart.print();
chart.setTitle({text:''});
Its working fine, but title show inside chart lines. I am unable to resolve it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this instead

```
exportButton:{
            menuItems: null,
            onclick:function(){
                var fileName = "AAAA";//it's dynamic in reality.                                    
                this.exportChart({filename : fileName});
             }
         }
```

exportChart method takes options parameter too..